# Maven - Multiple Jar Best Practices

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, executable-jar

Maven best practices seem like they support one project > one jar > one pom.xml.

I have a maven project that can compile and run as a command line program OR as a GUI. Is it bad to have one project with one POM file that creates 2 jars in this case (one for each run type)? Or is there a better way to do it?

Also, I have automated tests in my test package that compile and run as jar files. Is it a bad practice to keep those in the maven test structure and use the same pom file to compile them? Or is it better to put them in a different project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in different projects, but in multiple maven modules within the same project.

Consider a maven module structure such as:

```
root
   core
   cli-api
   gui-api
```

where:

- the `core` module contains all the actual business logic, and builds a typical jar
- the `cli-api` module depends on `core`, and includes the code to run from the command line
- the `gui-api` module depends on `core` and includes the code to run from a gui

The test classes should be within the related module.

Comment: Thanks! I've never used modules before, but they were pretty straightforward. They worked beautifully; the project structure makes a lot of sense this way.